# Особо хитрое написание

Tags: php

```
$arr =array();
foreach ($cur_news_list as $news){
   empty($arr[$news['id']]) && ($arr[$news]['id'] = array());
   $arr[$news[id]][] = &$news;
}
```

Что происходит в третьей строчке?

```
empty($arr[$news['id']]) && ($arr[$news]['id'] = array());
```

Comment: Если `$arr =array();` определяется непосредственно перед искомой строкой, то первое условие на этой строке не имеет никакого смысла, т.к. всегда будет возвращаться false. Следовательно, всегда будет выполняться вторая часть условия - присвоение. А на вопрос "что происходит", в таком контексте можно сказать, что происходит "индусский код".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Присвоение значения, если не задано.
Если переписать с `if` будет

```
if (empty($arr[$news['id']]) { $arr[$news]['id'] = array(); }
```

P.S.: Похоже, что в строке `$arr[$news]['id'] = array();` ошибка - ключ в `empty($arr[$news['id']]` не соответствует ключу с права.
Вероятно нужно `$arr[$news['id']] = array();`

Comment: да там ошибка..

Answer (score 4):

Этот трюк связан с особенностью вычисления операндов операций `&&` (логическое И) и `||` (логическое ИЛИ).

PHP, как и ряд других языков программирования, умеет оптимизировать код при вычислении результатов логических операций. При этом, он использует следующие правила:

1. Если первый операнд оператора `&&` равен (или приводится к) `false`, то второй операнд **не вычисляется**, так как результат выражения все равно будет равен `false`.
2. Если первый операнд оператора `||` равен (или приводится к) `true`, то второй операнд **не вычисляется**, так как результат выражения все равно будет равен `true`.

При этом, если в операнд входит функция, обладающая побочными действиями то подобный трюк можно использовать как альтернативу конструкции `if`.

Типовой пример, встречавшийся 10 лет назад в каждом втором PHP приложении выглядел следующим образом:

```
$link = mysql_connect('...') or die('Cannot connect');
```

Если переписать этот код с использованием `if`, получим:

```
$link = mysql_connect('...');
if (!$link) {
    die('Cannot connect')
}
```

Несмотря на некое сокращение кода, я бы не рекомендовал вам использовать подобный трюк в реальных приложениях. Далеко не всегда он позволяет сделать код более читаемым. (То же самое, кстати, относится к присваиванию в условиях.)

---

Теперь несколько слов о вашем конкретном случае. Код

```
empty($arr[$news['id']]) && ($arr[$news]['id'] = array());
```

Будет понят PHP как следующий набор инструкций:

```
if (empty($arr[$news['id']])) {
    $arr[$news]['id'] = array();
}
```